# What's the deeper meaning of 配跑?

Tags: cantonese

I don't understand [this dialog at 59:56](https://youtu.be/jEh_pedsM-4?t=3596) in Miss H.K. 2020. Patrick Lam (林溥來) asks contestant #7 Ceci Mak (麥詩晴)

> 除了你自己，你觉得邊個佳麗同你_跑?

> My translation — Besides yourself, which other contestant do you think _跑 with you?

1. I don't know how to write pui in pui pao...陪 or 配?

Mak answers

> Roxanne [Ho (何孟珊)], 因为我觉得佢会跑赢.

> — Roxanne, because I think she will run win.

Lam then comments

> 佢明明咩意思。

> — She understood the meaning.

2. What's deeper meaning does Patrick Lam allude?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was "陪跑" = "also-run" (to accompany the one who will win in a competition,  with little chance of winning herself)

It came from a Chinese saying 陪太子讀書 (to accompany the prince in studying) meaning 'you are just there to take part, not expecting to win - your role is to make the prince (winner) look good'

The question: "Besides yourself, which contestant do you consider come here to be your also-ran?". The host wanted to ask if she considers herself should win, who will be the runners-up? but "陪跑" might not be a very accurate term to describe the runners-up. If someone ends up being the runner-up, she did have a chance of winning

> [also-ran](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/also-ran): a contestant that does not win

The comment was "佢明唔明咩意思?" (does she understand what it means?) When saying 明唔明/ming4 m4 ming4/ too quickly the /m4/ sound might merge with the beginning of the second /ming4/ and the phrase would sound like /ming(mm)ing(4)/